# How to troubleshoot Start-job scriptblock that runs forever?

Tags: powershell, start-job

I have difficulties troubleshooting scriptblock used in start-job.

Basically I wanted to get WMI properties for servers. If I issue the following command from Powershell, it works.

```
c:/>$wmi=Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer servername
```

However, if I run the command in scriptblock of start-job, the job runs forever.

```
c:/> start-job -argumentList servername -scriptblock {$wmi=Get-wmiobject 
-class win32_operatingsystem -computer $args[0]}

C:/> get-job
Id   Name    State     HasMoreData   Location    Command
--   ----    -----     -----------   --------    -------
169  Job169  Running   True          localhost   $wmi=Get-WmiObject -cl...
```

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this on Windows XP? There is a known issue with WMI on Windows XP and Start-Job. Read this thread: [WMI Query Script as a Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314180/wmi-query-script-as-a-job)

This could be due to corrupt WMI repository. Try rebuilding it once.

Comment: yes, it is on XP. Really appreciate your information.  I've never thought of this is a issue with WMI on XP!!!

Comment: I followed the instructions given in the link to rebuild the repository but didn't fix.  However, the start-job command worked on a Win2003 server!!!